# How do I make my music bot resume playing?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Here's my play.js. I am not a coder, so I don't understand most of this code. It took a bit of troubleshooting for it to work.

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');

module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    description: 'plays a song or whatever.',
    async execute(message, args) {
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;

        if(!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('lol u need to be in a voice channel first');
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if(!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('u dont have the correct permissions smh');
        if(!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('u dont have the correct permissions smh');
        if(!args.length) return message.channel.send('ok, but u need to tell me what u want to play');

        const validURL = (str) =>{
            var regex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/;
            if(!regex.test(str)){
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        if(validURL(args[0])){
            const connection = await voiceChannel.join();
            const stream = ytdl(args[0], {filter: 'audioonly'});

            connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
            .on('finish', () =>{
                voiceChannel.leave();
                message.channel.send('ok fine ill leave')
            });

            await message.reply(`ok ill play whatever that is`)

            return
        }

        const connection = await voiceChannel.join();

        const videoFinder = async (query) => {
            const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);

            return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
        }

        const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));

        if(video){
            const stream = ytdl(video.url, {filter: 'audioonly'});
            connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 0.5})
            .on('finish', () =>{
                voiceChannel.leave();
            });

            await message.reply(`ok im now playing ***${video.title}***`)
        } else {
            message.channel.send('lol i cant find the video ur looking for.')
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my pause.js. I had a bit of problem with this one, but it took me a while and a few searches to fix it.

```
    name: 'pause',
    description: 'makes me pause or whatever',
    async execute(message,args, command, client, Discord){
        const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
        const stream = ytdl(args[0], {filter: 'audioonly'});
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
        const connection = await voiceChannel.join();
        const streamOptions = {seek:0, volume:1}
        DJ = connection.play(stream, streamOptions)
        DJ.pause();
    }
}
```

and finally, my resume.js (It doesn't work.)

```
    name: 'resume',
    description: 'makes me resume or whatever',
    async execute(message,args, command, client, Discord){
        const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
        const stream = ytdl(args[0], {filter: 'audioonly'});
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
        const connection = await voiceChannel.join();
        const streamOptions = {seek:0, volume:1}
        DJ = connection.play(stream, streamOptions)
        DJ.resume();
    }
}
```

I watched a tutorial on how to make a music bot. However, they didn't mention how to make a play/pause command. Whenever I ran the resume.js, it'd say Error: No video id found: undefined. This is the last command before I am done with my music bot (so far) It would be greatly appreciated if anyone can answer me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will need an instance of [`StreamDispatcher`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/StreamDispatcher) to call the method on. You could try to retrieve that instance from the message object.

```js
const dispatcher = message.guild.voice.connection.dispatcher;
dispatcher.pause();
```

But be aware that some of the properties could be `undefined`. So add safety checks.

```js
if (!message.guild) return;
const voiceState = message.guild.voice;
if (!voiceState || !voiceState.connection) return;
const dispatcher = voiceState.connection.dispatcher;
if (!dispatcher) return;
dispatcher.pause();
```

And you could apply the same logic with `dispatcher.resume()`.

**EDIT:** *Answer matches with the first revision of the question. The OP made significant changes to his question before I was able to answer. (Also I didn't see that an edit was made to the question.)*